# How to set a FrameLayout fill_parent in width and always have a fixed ratio in height?

Tags: android, android-layout

I see some questions about "ImageView"s, but I need a `FrameLayout`.

I have a FrameLayout, which I need its `width:height` = `2:1`, and the width is `fill_parent`. There are many image views inside the frame layout, I can just set them `width=fill_parent` and `height=fill_parent`.

I don't find a way to do this, please help .

My xml code is:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frameView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/card_style1"
            />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: In code its pretty easy, post a `Runnable` from the `onCreate` method where you get the `FrameLayout`'s width and calculate and set the height based on the calculated value. Directly in the xml layout there is no way to do this.

Comment: @Luksprog, could you give me an example? I don't find how to do it after a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you want:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    final FrameLayout target = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_id);
    target.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {             
            int width = target.getWidth();
            int height = width / 2;                
            LayoutParams lp = target.getLayoutParams(); 
            lp.height = height;
            target.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: The strange thing is `target.getWidth()` always return 0? I just updated my question to add some code.

Comment: @Freewind Sorry, there was a mistake in my code(replaced `new Handler()` with `target`). The `Runnable` should be posted using a view not a `Handler`, so the widths and heights will be available.